# Not able to change username in repository preferences in xcode

Tags: xcode

[image]

I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335015/change-the-username-for-git-in-xcode/23290581#23290581) but I don't understand where I should hit these command. On which path. If there is any other way to do this please help me.

Comment: use terminal for executing command , First go to the terminal  then go to your specific directory where your project is located and then apply this command . and still facing issue please let me know

Comment: Yes Ravi, my judgment was same I did this but nothing happening.

Comment: it is showing that but have you tried to commit files ? Under the Source Control menu it is showing or not ?

Comment: cause same is showing in my project but i m able to commit on GIT