# Why all my Xcode commits to Bitbucket show other user 'Author Name' on Bitbucket?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket, commit

When I commit and push code to bitbucket, my bitbucket show some other Author name. I used :

```
~ mymac$ git config --global user.name "Myfirstname lastname" 
:~ mymac$ git config --global user.email "myemail@abcd.com" 
:~ mymac$ git config user.name "myusername" 
:~ mymac$ git config user.email "myemail@abcd.com" 
:~ mymac$ cat .git/config:
```

### Above command show right email and password. But this will only work if I commit from terminal commands. However, in my case I am committing code directly from Xcode. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys fortunately I found the solution to this question: Xcode use your contact card from address book as Author name to all the commits. You can change whatever username/author name you want to show on Bitbucket/Git, follow this link
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22743?locale=en_US
 to make a contact as your contact card. Check screenshots also. Select any contact and make your contact card as displayed in screenshot.
*Happy Coding!!!*
------------------------------------------------------------------------[image]